# Is it possible to see only questions with zero answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a page that display questions with 0 answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/is-there-a-page-that-display-questions-with-0-answers)

I was just surfing the unanswered questions, trying to find the "truly" unanswered questions, rather than just those with very few (and no upvoted) answers...

...is there any way to get that view?

Comment: I think there is an RFE for more search options (here, somewhere among the most voted).

Comment: Seconded! The "Unanswered" category is a bit misleading....