# Asking questions brings up better Related questions than search

Tags: support, search, related-questions, relevance

I wanted to ask a question about filtering search results to truly unanswered questions, so I did a search for:

> ["zero answers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22zero+answers%22)

This got 4 hits on the "relevance" page, none of which was all that relevant, so I clicked over to the "Ask Question" page and entered this text:

> "Mopping up" - query to limit questions to those with zero answers

The "related questions" list *immediately* popped up, with the first item being [see only questions with zero answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4583/see-only-questions-with-zero-answers-closed).  Shouldn't that have been the first thing to appear on the "relevance" tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're kind of .. doing it wrong.

Try searching for this (put it in quotes)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22zero+answers%22

Or, use the new intitle:1 search operator (since that's what the ask page does).

Note that "answers" as a search term will be auto-mapped to a tag search since [answers] is a top 20 tag here on meta-so.

Comment: Where is the `intitle:1 search operator` documented?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Answer (score 3):

Status by design, which is to say that SO search could use some improvement.  Try google with site:stackoverflow.