# Why Inside 'Unanswered' tag there are questions that have already been answered?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Unexpected Results From Clicking The Unanswered Button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/unexpected-results-from-clicking-the-unanswered-button)
>   [is there a page that display questions with 0 answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/is-there-a-page-that-display-questions-with-0-answers)

Checking on the "[Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered)" tag in SO, there are questions that already have answers.

[http://lh5.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SnWk1k_9TUI/AAAAAAAAFD8/j4AJWVmkuV4/s400/answered.jpg](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/nJasPQasa8Y0k2_uh5bCpQ?feat=embedwebsite)

Or is it that by "Unanswered", you are referring to there are no answer with upvotes? If this were the case you might want to change it to something else more descriptive.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/

Comment: see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11249

Comment: and: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675

Comment: If you want I can make a greasemonkey script for it. I have a similar script so it would just take a few tweaks.

Comment: Greasemonkey for dupe finds?

Comment: Ill start on that when I actually have enough rep to see the duplicate menu

Answer (score 1):

It refers to questions that do not have an answer accepted or upvoted. It has been discussed at, for example, [[confusing top level SO buttons (questions and unanswered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11249/confusing-top-level-so-buttons-questions-and-unanswered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11249/confusing-top-level-so-buttons-questions-and-unanswered)

When you select the 'Unanswered' tab you can see, near the top right of the page the number of questions on the site that are, as it says, "questions with no upvoted answers".

So they are questions that have not received a well-regarded answer (or, perhaps, have a good answer but no-one has seen it and upvoted it).

Comment: You forgot "ad nauseum" at the start of your second sentence. Feels like it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this could be looked at as a veiled feature request:  make the results of the Unanswered search more obviously 'unanswered,' or 'not answered well.'

One possible way to do this would be to change the way that the style of the answer count indicator box is modified.  It is pretty obvious to users that when a new question is submitted, the answer count is 0.  This is obvious because the UI shows a box which says `0 answers`.  Also, the style of the box carries this meaning (on SO, the background of the box is maroon).  When the first answer arrives, the text of the answer count changes and so does the style of the box.

It would be helpful (in the unanswered tab as well in other list views) to know that there are no upvotes on answers.  This could be accomplished by keeping the style of the box as is until there is an upvote. The view would show the answer count but you would be provided with subtle feedback that there still is a need for strong answers.