# Position of Unanswered Question button

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, design

Why is the Unanswered questions button up the top next to badges? In my mind, it makes more sense for it to be a sub section of the questions section, with the hot questions and others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [confusing top level SO buttons (questions and unanswered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11249/confusing-top-level-so-buttons-questions-and-unanswered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack Overflow Trilogy revolves around answering questions. Thus, since there is space, and because it is one of the most important links on the whole site, it is placed in that navigation bar.