# How can you see all questions with 0 answers?

Tags: feature-request, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a page that display questions with 0 answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/is-there-a-page-that-display-questions-with-0-answers)

How can you see all questions with 0 answers on stackoverflow? I find trolling the "unanswered" sections, that most of the questions are indeed answered just people were too lazy to upvote the answers or accept the answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to accomplish this, sadly. I wouldn't be surprised if this got a <kbd>status-declined</kbd>, though. After all, the point is to get every question answered, not just the ones that will make you eligible for the Enlightened badge.

However, if you're noticing posts that show up in Unanswered but actually have a viable answer, why not take the 0.5 seconds and upvote the answer? That way, we can clear up the clutter a bit, eh?

Comment: If I understand it right, up-voting the answer won't necessarily help clear up the clutter. It will give additional rep to the person who answered, but the OP has to accept the answer for it to be removed from the unanswered questions page.

Comment: The unanswered tab says 'questions with no upvoted answers'

Comment: You're wrong, Colin. Unanswered means: no answer or only answers without an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 384 of them (according to the latest data dump), I looked at a few and a lot got migrated or closed:

```
select * from Questions 
where AnswerCount = 0
```

You can use the data dump to find them. You can also filter on low view count, or high questioner rep.

For your enjoyment, here is the oldest unanswered question on stackoverflow is:

[Aqua Data Studio - Shortcuts for Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157969)