# Filtered Questions Asked By Accepted Answer/ No Accepted Answer

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I think it's helpful if we can go to a page and view all *our own* questions that

1. Does not have an accepted answer,
   and/or
2. Does not have an answer yet.

The reason I asked for them is because, I sometimes need to review through all the questions, and pick those that don't have proper answers so that I can perform further operations on them ( such as offering a bounty, or accept an existing answer).

Comment: I proposed a threshold to filter unanswered questions here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pop these slices of french toast queries into the site search:

For your own questions without an accepted answer:

> [user:me hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:0)

For those that do not have an answer yet:

> [user:me answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+answers:0)

Butter up, sprinkle with sugar and enjoy.

Comment: "hasaccepted:0 wiki:0 closed:0 user:me" also filters out closed and wiki ones. Add "answers:1" and you almost have the "All questions preventing you from reaching 100%" view, the only missing criteria "question must be 3 days or older"