# What to do when someone posts a stupid answer to your question

Tags: feature-request, site-usage

I get this every #%*@Q%& time I post. I take about 15-20 minutes to craft my question with all the details, formatted perfectly, etc., and then 1 minute after it's posted, some moron comes in and posts something completely ridiculous and unhelpful. Sure, I can downvote him, but the problem is, now my question is marked with "an answer" so people hunting through the questions looking for "unanswered" questions skip over mine and it looks like my question is taken care of, even though it's not.

Could there be some way to make an "unacceptable answer" that only the OP can designate so as to not make it appear that the OP is being helped, or something of the sort? What do I do in this situation where now no one comes to my question because it's been "answered"?

Thanks

**EDIT** When I say "answered" vs "unanswered" i don't mean ACTUALLY answered, as in having an accepted answer or not, I mean having AN ANSWER. For instance, I sometimes just hit the SO logo and look for red "0 answer" squares .

Comment: That glowing square of "0" answers is alluring.

Answer (score 6):

Answers only remove the question from the "unanswered" list if the answer is upvoted

So actually, downvoting would be the right thing to do - it might even discourage the other user from behaving in this manner in the future. I would always assume good faith though, and leave a comment indicating why you don't think it answers the question

Answer (score 5):

> the problem is, now my question is marked with "an answer" so people hunting through the questions looking for "unanswered" questions skip over mine

How so? Unanswered is defined as "no upvotes on any answers", and it is that way for the very reasons you describe.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

You'll also find plenty of people on meta *complaining* about this definition of unanswered. It might be instructive for those people to read your post to understand why it is in fact defined that way.

Comment: relatedly, if a question has *only* negative score answers, could it be visually different from those with 0 upvoted answers? Maybe showing the same color as 'real' 0 answers, but with a number attached?

Comment: @warren that's a pretty good solution, i think

Answer (score 2):

Just down vote it and maybe add some comment. Your question stays in [Unanswered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) tab, until one of the answers is upvoted.

Maybe there should be some visual difference between questions with non-upvoted answers and questions with upvoted answers in question listings. Like there is a difference between questions without answers and questions with answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's REALLY annoying.

(I WAS going to just post the above line on its own, hehe)

Actually your question DOES stay on the unanswered tab until an answer is accepted.

See [link to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/is-there-a-page-that-display-questions-with-0-answers)

Comment: Nope, upvoting removes question from unanswered tab, no accepting needed. See Atwoods's answer to this question.