# Is there an easy way to see all questions in a tag that have 0 answers?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a page that display questions with 0 answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/is-there-a-page-that-display-questions-with-0-answers)

I'd like to see all of the questions that exist with a given tag, but don't have any answers.

When I look in the "Unanswered" tab, that's what I'm expecting. Instead I see all questions without an accepted answer.

Is there an easy way to find questions with zero proposed answers?

If there isn't, we can turn this into a community wiki question and discuss the merits of this means of navigation.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675

Answer (score 4):

Use the built-in search and enter:

```
[support] answers:0
```

Returns all support questions without an answer on this site.
BTW: "Unanswered" means: Has no answers or only answers without an upvote.

Comment: Thanks, but what is "[support] answers:0"?

Comment: Use the built-in search (upper right corner). If you search for a tag, use [tag]. If you search for answers=0, use answers:0. Details: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: According to the search details page linked in the comment above, `answers:0` will return all the questions with a *minimum* of 0 answers.  Is the search behaviour different when you use *0* rather than a positive integer?

Comment: With *0* you get all questions with 0 answers. With *2* you get all questions with 2 answers and above.

Answer (score -2):

No, it doesn't seem like there is.  There is a search option to find all question with a *minimum* number of answers, but not maximum.  Negating the search doesn't help either.  It would be nice if the advanced search options included a max-answers option, so you could do e.g.

```
[feature-request] maxanswers:0
```