# I want to view the unanswered questions per tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there an easy way to see all questions in a tag that have 0 answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14147/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-all-questions-in-a-tag-that-have-0-answers)
>   [How to search unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16542/how-to-search-unanswered-questions)

I'm not sure it's possible to view these pages and if it is possible, it's very un-intuitive to get to them

Answer (score 8):

Say you want to see all the questions tagged **[sifr]** with zero (0) answers. Plop this into [the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search):

> [[sifr] answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers:0+[sifr])

What returns will be all questions with absolutely no answers under that specific tag. Salt and pepper to your tastes.

Comment: And Guy thought it was unintuitive... for shame.

Answer (score 0):

Possible (a bit more intuative than search):

> http://www.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/<strike>java</strike> (your tag here)

Comment: That just gets you "questions with no upvoted answers" not "questions with no answers". There's a subtle, but important, difference between those two statements ;)

Comment: But he requested unanswered - I assumed he meant unanswered as defined by the site.