# Only show questions with no answers

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a page that displays questions with zero answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/is-there-a-page-that-displays-questions-with-zero-answers)

Is it possible to only show question which are not yet answered?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14147/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-all-questions-in-a-tag-that-have-0-answers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming it is "no answer" what you meant: just search for `answers:0`

After you search something, there is a help link at the right sidebar: [See our search tips!](https://stackoverflow.com/search) for more details